# how to generic .htaccess to prevent hotlink

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, hotlinking

The following code works fine:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://superwebx.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|swf|css)$ - [F]
```

but I want to make a generic script serve me for several sites I manage, but fails try to get

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://%{HTTP_HOST}/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|swf|css)$ - [F]
```

Comment: This is a seriously useful question.  I'm building one .htaccess that I want to reuse on a bunch of sites, so a generic hotlink prevention RewriteCond would be superb!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use variables inside the regex. You can work around this by using a RegEx backreference like so:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^/]+)/ [NC]
RewriteCond %1#%{HTTP_HOST} !^(.+)#\1$
RewriteRule \.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|swf|css)$ - [F]
```

(note the `#` is just used as a boundry. It could be any character that isn't used in domain-names.)

Answer (score 1):

Very old one, but here's your answer:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}@@%{HTTP_REFERER} !^([^@]*)@@https?://\1/.*
```