# Dynamically prevent hotlinking images using htaccess for multiple domains

Tags: image, .htaccess, dns, hotlinking

Preventing hotlinking using htaccess is well documented. However, I want to prevent hotlinking for multiple domains without adding a rule per domain.

My idea is to match the referrer with the hostname, this seems like a good solution to me.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?%{HTTP_HOST}/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ - [NC,F,L]
</IfModule>
```

Is this is a proper and safe solution to prevent hotlinking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work when the request comes with `www.` but the referrer doesn't. That's because your rule would effectively try to match the following which wouldn't work.

```
RewriteCond http://domain.com/index.php !^http://(www\.)?www\.domain\.com/.*$
```

The correct way is to use the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://(www\.)?([^/]+)/.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %2#%{HTTP_HOST} !^(.+)#(www\.)?\1$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(bmp|gif|jpe?g|png|swf)$ - [F,L,NC]
```

This takes care of SSL (`https:`) as well. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17454709/1237040) to see how it works.