# How To Prevent DIrect Access To Image Files?

Tags: php

What's the best way to prevent direct access to image files on a server?
Let's say I've some important images/documents on a web server which are uploaded by the customers.

Now, what's the best way I can use to secure all those image files so that unauthorized users can't access/download them?

Comment: Use a `.htaccess` file

Comment: Can you provide me an example?

Comment: this is an opinion based question. Please rephrase, but the pros and cons of diffrent approaches to prevent hotlinking has been discussed endlessly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically prevent hotlinking images using htaccess for multiple domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18229429/dynamically-prevent-hotlinking-images-using-htaccess-for-multiple-domains)

Comment: Are you trying to make it so unauthorized users can't access them *at all*, or are you trying to make it so unauthorized users can "view" but not "download" them? The latter is impossible, but the former isn't.

Comment: Images contains private data of company, such as Employee Govt. ID, License and many other details. Only Admins can have access to those images and I want to protect those files from being hacked or view by unauthorized users.